# Toggle RadioButton in a custom row of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

Everytime I open the target activity, I loop through the custom row in my ListView to search for a particular value.

```
 private void setSelectedProfile() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("SPD", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
        if (String.valueOf(lv.getItemAtPosition(i)).equals(sp.getString("default", ""))) {
            // code that I needed
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Soon as the loop found it, I need to toggle the radio button inside the custom row. I tried to find and apply their solutions but none fit my case.

How can I access the RadioButton so that I can toggle them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it inside getView method in your ListView adapter. Something like this:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private SharedPreferences sp;
    private List<String> data;

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull List<String> data) {
        super(context, -1, data);
        this.data = data;     
        sp = context.getSharedPreferences("SPD", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        // init views 
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton ) rowView.findViewById(R.id.radioButton);


        // toggle the radio button 
        if (data.get(position).equals(sp.getString("default", ""))) {
              radioButton.setChecked(!radioButton.isChecked());
        }

        // bind other views

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! I was staring at the block of code of getView method but not sure what to add there. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Mr.Nacho I'm glad it helped :-)